# parse xml multiple sibling child node before specific xml sibling child node using php

Tags: php, arrays, xml

Hello Stackoverflowrian!
im trying to parse multiple mathml(xml) child node before specific child node which is `<mspace breakline="newline"` into an array. here are my .xml file

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML">
<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>
<mspace linebreak="newline"/>
<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn><mo>-</mo><mn>2</mn>
<mspace linebreak="newline"/>
<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn>
<mspace linebreak="newline"/>
<mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>
```

thats mean i want to get like this

```
$array(0)=<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>+</mo><mn>2</mn><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn>;
$array(1)=<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>3</mn><mo>-</mo><mn>2</mn>;
$array(2)=<mn>2</mn><mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mn>1</mn>;
$array(3)=<mi>x</mi><mo>=</mo><mfrac><mn>1</mn><mn>2</mn></mfrac>;
```

currently my coding is

```
<?php

$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('answer.xml'));
$xml1 = $xml1->asXml();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml1);
$maths = $dom->getElementsByTagName('mspace');
$length = 0;
foreach ($maths as $math) {
$length++;
}


$root = simplexml_load_string($xml1);
for($i = 0; $i <= $length; $i++){
    foreach($root as $child)
    {
    if ($maths){ 
        $arrXml[] = $child->asXml();
         // break;
        }

    // 
    }
 print_r(array_values($arrXml));    
    break;
}
```

which give me output

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => x [2] => + [3] => 2 [4] => = [5] => 3 [6] => [7] => 2 [8] => x [9] => = [10] => 3 [11] => - [12] => 2 [13] => [14] => 2 [15] => x [16] => = [17] => 1 [18] => [19] => x [20] => = [21] => 12 );
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it could be to loop the [children](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and to create an array for all items that do not have `mspace` as a name.

Once the name is equal to `mspace`, create a new empty array and add that to a placeholder array `$result` for all those results.

After the looping use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) with [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to create whole strings for the array entries.

```
$xml1 = new SimpleXMLElement(file_get_contents('answer.xml'));
$counter = 0;
$result = [];

foreach ($xml1->children() as $child) {
    if ($child->getName() === "mspace") {
        $result[++$counter] = [];
        continue;
    }
    $result[$counter][] = $child->saveXML();
}
$result = array_map(function($x){
    return implode("", $x);
}, $result);

print_r($result);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/TQnmZ)